# how to create a custom landing [home]page in sharepoint using page layouts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Would like to know,how to create a custom landing[home]page in sharepoint using page layouts and few cutom web parts.
my env:  SP 2013 / VS 2012 / SP D 2013 
I have gone through kirk evans blog and I created a new "Publishing Content Type" page layout in SharePoint Designer 2013 whose content type was "Page". 
Have created 2 visual web parts for my left navigation- its a custom links web part- and  for right hand navigation also i have created another custom links web part as a separate SP Solution.
now I am not able to continue from here.
i am stuck with this point.
Can anyone help me how can i continue creating a custom home page with 3 web parts[ 3 columns ] 
a) one on  left hand navi.
b) middle zone - it can be a contente ditor wp
c) right hand side navigation - links web part

help is appreciated!

[image: MYLANdINGpage-image-in-sp-d]

Comment: i think no one has faced this issue yet. can any SP experts help me here.